# Special finite subcover of a compact

Tags: gn.general-topology, real-analysis

Let $(a,b)\in \mathbb R^n$. We consider the following open cover of the compact line segment $[a,b]$:  $$[a,b]\subset\underset{x\in [a,b]}{\bigcup}B(x,\rho_x),$$
where for $x\in K,B(x,\rho_x)$ is a given nonempty open ball of center $x$.

Since $[a,b]$ is compact, there exist a finite subcover such that
$$[a,b]\subset\underset{1\leq k\leq n}{\bigcup}B(x_k,\rho_{x_k}).$$

I would want to know if we can always construct the above subcover such  that 
$$x_{k+1}\in B(x_k,\rho_{x_k}),$$
for all $k\in\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$.

Comment: Surely, you hae some additional assumption?

Comment: consider e.g. $X=\mathbb{R}$, $K =\{0,1\}$, $\rho_0=\rho_1=1/2$.

Comment: Please see the edit

Comment: It is a good question, and the negative answer is nice to know.  But I would use neither general-topology nor banach-spaces as its tag.

Comment: I added tag real-analysis

Comment: Is this question really on-topic here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. Consider the interval $[0,2]$, and define $\rho_x$ as follows:

1- For $x=1$, let $\rho_x=0.5$

2- For $x\neq 1$, Let $\rho_x$  be the distance from $x$ to $1$, so $\rho_x=|1-x|$

Now suppose that a subcovering $B(x_i,\rho_i)$, $i=1\cdots,n$ of the wanted form exists. By the choice of the $\rho_x$, the unique open ball $B(x,\rho_x)$ containing $1$ is $B(1,\rho_1)$. Thus $B(1,\rho_1)$ must be the first ball of the subcovering, and without loss of generality, we can suppose that $x_2<1$. Then by the choice of $\rho_2$, $B(x_2,\rho_2)\subseteq (0,1)$. Since $x_3\in B(x_2,\rho_2)$, then $x_3<1$ and $B(x_3,\rho_3)\subseteq (0,1)$ for the same reason as above.

So by an easy induction, we show  for all $i=2\cdots,n$ that $B(x_i,\rho_i)\subset (0,1)$. The union of the $B(x_i,\rho_i)$ for $i=1,\cdots,n$ is then contained in $[0,\frac{3}{2})$. Contradiction.